# Не могу создать БД через localdb\v12.0

Tags: база-данных, sql-server, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-localdb

Я могу создать БД с именем сервера (localDB)\MSSQLLocalDB,
но не могу создать ее с именем сервера (localdb)\v12.0, как в туториалах в интернете. MS SQL 2014. SqlLocalDB.exe выдает только одну строку, MSSQLLocalDB. 
Как я могу сделать так, чтобы обращаться еще и по (localdb)\v12.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что ж, SqlLocalDB.exe позволяет зарегистрировать дополнительное имя экземпляра SQL Server, что я и сделал. Запустил cmd, далее ввел:
 SqlLocalDB.exe
 SqlLocalDB create "v12.0"

Теперь работает.